# Reducing a matrix over a field of 3 elements

Tags: matrices, finite-fields

I have the augmented matrix

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 & 1\\
1 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

And I need to reduce it to reduced echelon form over a field of three elements ($\mathbb{F}_{3}$)

If I reduce the matrix over $\mathbb{Q}$ I get:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 2\\
0 & 1 & 0 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & -1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$

I do get the concept of field, but I have no idea how apply it in order to reduce the matrix over a field of 3 elements. Do I have to make it e.g. 3=3-3=0 (Subtract by the number of elements in the field)?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You do the same as for $\mathbf Q$, except the field has only the elements $1,-1,0$.

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be F={0,1,2} and not F={1, -1, 0}

Comment: That depends on the convention for the choice of representatives. I think for multiplications, it's simpler to use $-1$ than $2$.